# Third smallest number in matrices and its addition

Tags: c

How can i addition one + one matric (array data structure) and after it find the third smallest number in it in C language (not C++)? Thank you for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code follows:

```
void addMatrix(unsigned int size, double const * const a, double const * const  b, double * const res) {
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < size * size; ++i)
       res[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

double findThirdSmallest(unsigned int size, double const * const input) {
   //save the three smallest values inside res
   double res[3];
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
       res[i] = LDBL_MAX;
   }
   for (i = 0; i < size * size; ++i) {
       int j;
       for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
           if (input[i] < res[j]) {
               int k;
               for (k = 2; k != j; --k) {
                   res[k] = res[k - 1];
               }
               res[j] = input[i];
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   return res[2];
}
```

EDIT: Changing the type and the size of the matrix will be your work.

Comment: And if i have int mat1[50][50],mat2[50][50] is is really nessesary to use double and LDBL_MAX ? Thx

Answer (score 0):

- First decide how to represent the matrix (hint: use an array of arrays)
- Then figure out how to add two matrices - this is simple
- Then, how do you find the 3rd smallest element in a sequence? There are many ways! Is efficiency especially important for you? What algorithmic complexity is required?

Comment: 1) For example int mat1[50][50],mat2[50][50];
2) I dont know how to do addition and after find the 3rd smallest element in the result and printf it - some kind of for cycle etc.

Comment: @Heigan: sure it's possible. Didn't you learn how matrix addition works? If not, try to find it online - should be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access SIMD instructions, I don't believe there is an approach that will do both at the same time.  If you are not trying to do use SIMD, then just keep a temp array of the three smallest values (like a priority queue) that is updated each time a sum is computed in the matrix.

If this were C++, the priority queue could be kept in a functor object used by the STL algorithms.

Comment: About your tip for keeping a temporary variable: note that it's somewhat more complex in his case since he seeks the 3rd smallest item, not *the* smallest item